# Android RBG image file to CMYK image File

Tags: android, image-processing, rgb, cmyk

I have many images in RGB format. I need to convert them to CMYK format and save them (no need to display the CMYK image on screen) to a file. I found many answers for converting RGB value to CMYK value but I dont know what to do with those CMYK values.I need to convert the whole RGB file and save it as CMYK file. How do I do that ?

Comment: that would depend on the file format you want to save your image to. you can either use some library that supports that kind of stuff or you implement it using the respective file specifications

Comment: file format can be jpeg or jpg or png. but the image format should be CMYK. Can you suggest few libraries if you know. I tried to google it but could not find.

Comment: png does not support cmyk as far as I know. for libraries use websearch. question is if this makes any sense. to me it is weird that you don't care about the file format. if you convert those images for a reason the format should matter